# get views starting x-y coordinates ontouch specific view

Tags: android, coordinates, ontouchlistener

> I am working on custom keyboard where i **need XY coordinates of touched
>   view.**
>
> First i tell you what i tried,
>
> I have called **getLeft()** on view object, which gives me left edge
>   measure in pixel and it gives x coordinate.
>
> Then i called **getRawX()** & **getRawY()** which is working, but not
>   fit for my purpose. Because as it gives XY coordinates on root layout,
>   but it gives different measures as i touch different places on same
>   view.
>
> So how can i get starting and ending XY coordinate when i touched on
>   view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your xml you will have to capture the click by placing the following in the views where you want to know the x and y coordinates.

```
android:onClick="findXY"
```

And then in your java place a function

```
public void findXY(View view) {
    int[] posXY = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
    int x = posXY[0];
    int y = posXY[1];
}
```

Comment: in my code view.getLocationOnScreen(posXY); returns zero, why is that